# Plot lines in log-scale (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, scale

I'm trying to plot a dash-line in a plot using:

```
ax.plot([dt.datetime(2012,01,27,18,19),
         dt.datetime(2012,01,27,18,19)], [0, 1300], 'k--', lw=2)
```

It works fine when I use linnear scale but when I define a log scale

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

the line dont appear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't show because you have the number 0 on the y axis, change it to something positive, e.g. 1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([dt.datetime(2012,01,27,18,19),
     dt.datetime(2012,01,27,18,19)], [1, 1300], 'k--', lw=2)
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

**Explanation:**

log(0) is not defined. Numpy returns `-inf` (which has some logic behind it), but if you try to draw a point with `inf` or `nan` value, it is not going to be drawn. With plots made of line segments this means that two line segments are going to disappear. Now you tried to draw a line between an existing point and a non-existing point. (You can verify this by changing the style to 'o'.)